# Where is the official documentation of gnu linker script command language?

Tags: reference, documentation, gnu, ld, linker-scripts

Search engine results for gnu linker script command language return pretty old (pre 1998) documentation. So where can one find the documentation for gnu ld's script command language?

What did I try? Search the web. What was I expecting? To find link to official+latest gnu linker command language manual.

Answer (score 1):

I fell for the same "trap" a couple of years ago. It's at https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/. Probably, you have the same thought that I had: because it doesn't look like official documentation at first glance, you didn't think it is official documentation.

Happened to me also a couple of years ago during my university years. I also created a blog post because of that: https://phip1611.de/blog/where-to-find-the-official-gnu-ld-documentation/